# Is there a better, 3rd party "Find" / "Search" add-on for Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, search, find

I can't stand Visual Studio 2008's "Find" or "Find and replace" functionality, does anyone know of a better 3rd party solution that integrates into visual studio?  At this point, I'd gladly take any "Find" utility, visual studio integration or not.

Some of the things VS.net 08 wont do that I'd like to do:

- let you specify the file type ("*.sql" would be nice)
- let you specify which solution or folder, "Current Project" seems like a waste or after thought

If anything else, just post your favorite "Find" app and I'll check them out

Comment: Pardon? VS does let you specify file types, "Current Solution", folders etc. etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Find is brilliant in VS 2008.

Do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to bring up the advanced find window.

Then you can do everything you asked about and more.

Comment: Wow, thanks.  I saw the regex stuff in the "find options" part of the quick find window, but I never noticed the "Find in files" window.  Not sure why they went out of their way to separate these different type of searches.

Comment: While this might be the thing the user was actually was looking for, it does not answer the question he was asking. I landed here because i was actually looking for a good replacement of the vs search and this answer is not helping at all.

Comment: FindInFiles (Visual Studio's default search tool) is *not* brilliant. Based entirely on out-dated regex technology it is simply inferior (in my opinion) to an information retrieval-based approach.  Note that two tools mentioned below are built on information retrieval technology, Entrian Source Search and Sando Code Search, and are available for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 6):

Entrian Source Search http://entrian.com/source-search/ is a Search addin for Visual Studio.  It builds a full-text index of your files, so searching is always near-instant.  The results are syntax-highlighted, and it supports filtering by file type, filename and directory.

Full disclosure: I'm the author (and I wrote it because I too was frustrated by Visual Studio's own search features ;-).

Comment: pricey, but looks pretty sweet

Answer (score 4):

The "Find in Files" command allows you to specify the file type, and allows you to specify exactly which folders to search in. It even allows the use of regular expressions.

Please try it out, and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

[Resharper](http://www.google.si/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jetbrains.com%2Fresharper%2Fdocs%2FReSharper40DefaultKeymap.pdf&ei=UaTsSeDlJ4e5jAel-_2aCg&usg=AFQjCNGQM0WzhBKP_Qyh7rd8t__v_zBdrQ&sig2=e9HIGK9g6Fp-GEcRp10Pzg).

Answer (score 3):

The **[Sando Code Search Tool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/06f39a31-20ce-408c-afee-8a02b484db1c)** is a free, open-source Visual Studio extension that searches your **C, C++, and C#** code.  It returns results as a list of program elements (e.g., methods, elements, fields, enums, etc), using a Google-like search engine to identify relevant results instead of the typical regular expression based approach. It supports exclusions (e.g., 'add file -test'), limit by filetype (e.g., 'add file filetype:cs'), and exact matching (e.g., '"AddFile(File);"') and includes conceptual autocomplete.

Sando searching a roguelike game for "add weapon".

[image]

Sando searching for an exact match using quotes and reviewing results with code snippet preview.

[image]

Supports: VS2010 (all versions), VS2012 (all versions)
Languages: C, C++, C#

**Full Disclosure:** I am the project lead for this extension and so I may be biased :)

Answer (score 1):

SonicFileFinder is pretty handy to use, if you want to search by filename. Allows you to type partial file name, and see all the matching filenames.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using VS2008 Standard Edition,and "Find In Files" did **not** appear as one of the choices in the Edit menu!

I had to add it via "Customize...".  Had to add the Ctrl+Shift+F shortcut via "Keyboard..." too.